# get notified with calltask launcher completed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I need to launch call task in my wp7 app. once i launch this task it dials the number but this task donot force my application to send in background so once call is ended my application comes back. How I can notified in my app that this task is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into the Unobscured event, unfortunately it doesn't give as much context as you would hope however if you know that you invoked the PhoneCallTask then you can be nearly sure that the Unobscured event occurred because you were returning from this Task :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.unobscured(v=vs.92).aspx